# How to have dynamic left-margin with Susy?

Tags: responsive-design, susy-compass

I am playing with the positioning of a .logo in this HTML:

```
 <div class="mod-header">
   <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
 </div>
```

The logo width is fixed, however I wonder if I should make the margin-left adjust to the screen size.

I have tried this with Susy, and this makes the .logo width fixed:

```
.logo
  text-indent: -9999px
  float: left
  +rem('width', 120px)
  +rem('margin', 20px 0)
  // margin-left: $column-width
```

However, this does not adjust the left-margin.
When I try:

```
 .logo
   @include span-columns(3,12)
```

There is some adjustment going on, but it is about the width, not the margin-left.

How would I approach this fixed width, left-margin adjustment?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
.logo
  width: 120px
  margin-left: gutter(12) + columns(2,12)
```

Comment: That works. There's a shortcut for columns + gutter, called space (e.g. `space(2,12)`). But there are even-shorter-cuts for handling [margins](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-helper-margin) - in this case you can use either `@include pre(2,12)` or `@include push(2,12)` (those are synonyms).